# Logging all Spring Boot http requests to the main log

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I want to log all http requests, minus actuator requests, in the main `spring.log` because I want to make them visible with [Spring Boot Admin](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin) through the actuator API. I understand that I can configure the embedded Tomcat of Spring Boot to log http requests, but these will not be revealed either in the actuator API or Spring Boot Admin. I also realize I can use the default `/trace` configuration but I would like more than the last 100 requests.

Currently, my strategy is to use a `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` to log the requests. **The problem here is if a request is not authenticated it never makes it to the interceptor.**

Interceptor:

```
@Component
class HttpRequestLoggingInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpRequestLoggingInterceptor.class)

    @Override
    void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        logger.info("HTTP Request - ${request.localAddr} - \"${request.method} ${request.servletPath}\" ${response.status}")
    }

}
```

AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private HttpRequestLoggingInterceptor interceptor

    @Override
    void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.addInterceptor(interceptor)
    }

}
```

WebMvcConfigurerAdapter:

```
@Configuration
@Order
class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private HttpRequestLoggingInterceptor interceptor

    @Override
    void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(interceptor).excludePathPatterns("/actuator/**")
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I tried adding a filter instead of an interceptor but unauthenticated requests are logged as 200 instead of 401s.